# How can I resolve my react hook TypeError: setUser is not a function problem?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm doing just basic stuff. I've one input field and a button wrap inside of form tag. using `useState` hook for setting input user name. 
browser is giving me error:- `TypeError: setUser is not a function` and fault in line no. 21.

```
  18 |   type="text"
  19 |   placeholder="nick name"
  20 |   value={user}  
> 21 |   onChange={ e => { setUser(e.target.value) } }
     | ^  22 | />
  23 | <button type="submit" onClick={StartQuiz}>
  24 |   Start the Quiz
```

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { QuizContext } from "../Helpers/Context";

function MainMenu() {
  const { user, setUser } = useState("");
  const { setGame } = useContext(QuizContext);

  const StartQuiz = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setGame("quiz");
    setUser("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="Menu">
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="nick name"
          value={user}  
          onChange={ e => { setUser(e.target.value) } }
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={StartQuiz}>
          Start the Quiz
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useState returns an array, not an object.

```
// this is wrong
//const { user, setUser } = useState("");
// this is correct
const [ user, setUser ] = useState("");
```

Answer (score 2):

you used curly brackets instead of **square brackets**. just change your code to

```
const [ user, setUser ] = useState("");
```

and it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you have an issue with how you declared the useState in with {} and not [].

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import { QuizContext } from "../Helpers/Context";

function MainMenu() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const { setGame } = useContext(QuizContext);

  const StartQuiz = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setGame("quiz");
    setUser("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="Menu">
      <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="nick name"
          value={user}  
          onChange={(e) => setUser(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={StartQuiz}>
          Start the Quiz
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainMenu;
```

Answer (score 0):

try use `onChange={ e => setUser(e.target.value)}` or defined a function

example:

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
         const {value, name} = e.target;
         setUser(value)
      }

 <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="nick name"
          value={user}  
          onChange={ handleChange } }
        />
```